# What scope does the enhanced for loop variable have in java?

Tags: java, foreach

Is the scope of the enhanced for loop (EFL) variable different for different classes in Java?

When I use an EFL over an `ArrayList` containing `Integer`s I cannot modify their values directly, however if I do the same thing for an `ArrayList` of `SimpleObject`s, defined in my code below, I can change the values of the instance variables with no problem.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

class SimpleObject{
  public int x;
  public SimpleObject() {
    this.x = 0;
  }
}

public class Simple {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    // Create an arraylist of Integers and SimpleObjects
    ArrayList<Integer> intList     = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<SimpleObject> soList = new ArrayList<SimpleObject>();

    // Add some items to the arraylists
    intList.add(1);
    intList.add(2);
    soList.add(new SimpleObject());
    soList.add(new SimpleObject());

    // Loop over the arraylists and change some values
    for (Integer _int : intList) {
      _int = 3; // Why doesn't this work but so.x = 5 below does?
    }
    for(SimpleObject so : soList) {
      so.x = 5;
    }

    // Loop over the arraylists to print out values
    for (Integer _int : intList) {
      System.out.println("integer = " + _int);
    }
    for(SimpleObject so : soList) {
      System.out.println("      x = " + so.x);
    }
  }
}
```

**Actual output:**

```
integer = 1
integer = 2
      x = 5
      x = 5
```

**Expected output:**

```
integer = 3
integer = 3
      x = 5
      x = 5
```

so my question is why doesn't `_int = 3;` persist in the first EFL, but `so.x = 5;` does in the second EFL?

Comment: `_int` is a *copy* of the reference to the `Integer`, so you are reassigning the `_int` variable, which is *local* to the `for` loop iteration. As soon as the loop is exited, the `_int` variable is out of scope and the `Integer` object would be garbage collected (if it was not cached by the `Integer` class, but that's another story).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Loop over the arraylists and change some values
for (Integer _int : intList) {
  _int = 3; // Why doesn't this work but so.x = 5 below does?
}
for(SimpleObject so : soList) {
  so.x = 5;
}
```

It is because you are assigning the value to `_int` but you are changing the value in `so`. Assignment and changing the value are completely different things.

You can understand it better with the following example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Changing - will work
        list.add("Hello");
        list.add("World");

        // Assigning - won't work
        list = null;
    }
}
```

If you want to change `intList`, you can use `List:set` as shown below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        intList.add(1);
        intList.add(2);

        for (int i = 0; i < intList.size(); i++) {
            intList.set(i, 3);
        }

        // Display
        intList.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
3
3
```

Comment: Ahh this makes sense, so if the Integer class happened to have a '`changeValue()`' method then `_int.changeValue(3)` would work?

Comment: Yes, you got the point.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is not that somehow scope rules are different, but that you do two different actions:

- `so.x = 3` sets the field `x` of the object referenced by `so` to 3.
- `_int = 3` sets `_int` to 3.

If you changed `so.x = 3` to `so = new SimpleObject` you would see that this too doesn't influence the content of the list you iterate over.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the scope of the enhanced for loop (EFL) variable different for different classes in Java?

No.  The scope of a variable declared in a `for` loop or extended `for` loop is the body of the loop.

> Why doesn't _int = 3; persist in the first EFL, but so.x = 5; does in the second EFL?

In the second example, you are not assigning to the loop variable `so`.

You are assigning to `so.x`.  That is a field of the object that the `so` variable refers to.

Then later you iterating over the list again and accessing the object which you previously updated.

The `so` variables in the two loops are different variables.